# List of Items vs. Data Source

Tags: ios, uitableview, datasource, uitabbar

When building a view for an iPhone app, one must consider how variable data will be determined by the view. Two design options jump readily to mind:

- An `NSArray` of items
- A `dataSource` property, which implements a protocol and returns the items.

The former is used by views such as [`UITabBar`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITabBar), while the latter is used by [`UITableView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). What are the pros and cons of these options? Is there a reason for the two distinct paradigms, or is one universally superior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly about the amount of data and limited amount of memory in relation to simplicity.

Simpler is always better if you can get away with it. A tab bar probably have less than 10 items which is no problem to hold in memory at once so the simplest solution is the best.

A table view however may have thousands of rows that may contain expensive data like images. Therefor it has a more complex design to be able to keep only the necessary data in memory.